# Adding random coloring variable to styling textlinks using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, variables, random

As the title says i'm trying to style all my textlinks to a random coloring variable using jquery.

For the last few days i get the random color variable up and running but i can't "connect" it to my css stylesheet or create script to have all the links the color of my random color variable.

i'm also trying to style the overall textlink styling like removing an underscore, might be super easy but it got me up the last 2 nights....

see here my variable:

```
$(function(){
    //col's voor random color balkon
    var col = 'rgb('+ (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) +',' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) + ','+(Math.floor(Math.random()*256))+')';
```

my script:

```
$("a") .add("a") .css("color", "col");
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't "col" your variable? Also why the .add("a"), doesn't the links already exists? If so, you should use it like so:

```
$("a").css("color", col);
```

As for your other question, I'm not too sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Removing link underscoring**

In your CSS file you can put:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

**Add Colour To Links**

To colour all your links differently, use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a').each(function() {
     var col = 'rgb('+ (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) +',' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) + ','+(Math.floor(Math.random()*256))+')';
     $(this).css('color', col);
    });
});
```

If you would prefer to have all your links 1 colour chosen at random, use jValdron's example:

```
$("a").css("color", col);
```

**Removing underscore and random color links**

If you don't want to put the link underscore removal in an external css file or at the top in `<style></style>` tags, you can add it to the above function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var col = 'rgb('+ (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) +',' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*256)) + ','+(Math.floor(Math.random()*256))+')';
        $(this).css('color', col);
        $(this).css('text-decoration', none);
    });
});
```

Comment: Matt thank you so much ! this worked perfectly for me ! I think i kind of get the structure now of building op a code like that!